# Minimal blocking cache store

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, latency

Suppose we have different methods which do some http calls, each of those are called with some specific argument... and we want to compare last value of method + argument and see if response was different and only then proceed...

```
method1(Arg arg)
method2(Arg arg)
```

when we make a particular call we have a hash of the response so that we can put them in a map...

```
{"key" : "method1|arg", "value" : "hash"}
```

now the next time we get the response we retrieve this particular "hash" from that cache store and compare it...

but all the method|arg calls are concurrent and there might be many calls of the same combination running in parallel, and only concurrency issue might happen on an Entry level... when the same call tries to update cache or read while the other one is updating...

So we need to synchronize on a entry object, and with that we will have that only a unique exact same combination of "method|arg" can block it... only the same call can block its other executions, and wont block other calls that have nothing to do with it.

I wonder if there is a lib (cache) already for this purpose?

if not, then is there any Map implementation that will allow to get Entry by key? or i shall keep another map?

and generally will it be safe to use HashMap and synchronize on Entry objects? (i dont really imagine what will happen when HashMap is rehashing and some concurrent gets are executing...)

**UPDATE**

Here is the implementation i've come up with... altough ConcurrentHashMap is probably covering this case but idea was to lock only on an entry not the entire map... (well except on writes)

```
public class HashCache {
  final HashMap<String, Holder> hashCache = new HashMap<>();

  public boolean hasChanged(String key, Object hash) {
    assert key != null && hash != null;

    Holder holder = hashCache.get(key);

    if (holder == null) {
      synchronized (hashCache) {
        hashCache.put(key, new Holder(hash));
      }
      return true; // first hash
    } else {
      synchronized (holder) {
        if (Objects.equals(holder.object, hash)) {
          return false; // hash not changed
        } else {
          holder.object = hash;
          return true; // hash changed
        }
      }
    }
  }

  private static class Holder {
    Object object;

    Holder(Object object) {
      this.object = object;
    }
  }
}
```

if you see a possible bug please comment :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'd be OK with a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html). I don't believe you need a cache for this, since you don't need to cache the response, but to store response's hash.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is a highly optimized `Map` which avoids thread contention as much as possible, especially for reads (I believe this matches your case).

You could use another approach and lock on every entry once you get it from a common `HashMap`, however I don't think it's worth the effort. I'd go first with the `ConcurrentHashMap` and test it, and would only change the implementation if behavior differs from expected results.

**EDIT:**

As per your edit, I must insist on recommending you use a `ConcurrentHashMap`. Anyways, if by some reason this is not affordable to you, I believe you should double-check when putting the value in the map for the first time:

```
public boolean hasChanged(String key, Object hash) {
    assert key != null && hash != null;

    Holder holder = hashCache.get(key); 
    if (holder == null) {
        synchronized (hashCache) { // Double-check that value hasn't been changed 
                                   // before entering synchronized block 
            holder = hashCache.get(key);
            if (holder == null) { 
                hashCache.put(key, new Holder(hash));
                return true; // first hash
            } // inner if
        }  // sync block
    } // outer if

    // No more else!

    synchronized (holder) {
        if (Objects.equals(holder.object, hash)) {
            return false; // hash not changed
        } else {
            holder.object = hash;
            return true; // hash changed
        }
    }
}
```

The double-check is needed because another thread might have put a value for the same key after your first `get()` but before you enter the `synchronized` block.

Comment: Thanks tough i've already implemented the HashMap approach :)

Comment: Please take a look at the update, is that looking fine?

Comment: @Vach Keep in mind that the built-in `ConcurrentHashMap` implementation is probably going to be more optimized than your own implementation so you may want to just use theirs if the refactor isn't too painful.

Comment: @JNYRanger I totally agree with you.

Comment: Thanks, this is for HFT related stuff, so i'm trying to controll any unnecessary object creation, and performance... Altough you're right ConcurrentHashMap divides data into shards and accesses them segment by segment, i think only microbenchmark and proper testing will reveal how this will perform... Will do that some time later :)

Comment: @Vach, I've edited my answer with a fix to your code. The only truth is microbenchmark results.